# combine two array then calculate it in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var arr1 = [123, 234, 565];
var arr2 = [2, 5, 1];

var arr = arr1.map(function(num, i) {
    if(i < arr1.length)
        return num + " " + arr2[i];

    return num;
});
```

Then I want to calculate every index in the array:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseFloat(arr[i])/100;
}
```

It just shows the array is `[12.3, 23.4, 56.5]`. But I want the result to be `[12.32, 23.45, 56.51]`. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: make the string an empty one and not include a space.

Comment: You're adding a space between the numbers you're concatenating in your `arr1.map` callback. So when you call `parseFloat` on this number, it is parsing the numbers before the space in the string, and leaving off the number you've added to the end after the space. Try changing `return num + " " + arr2[i];` to `return num + '' + arr2[i];`

Comment: What's the point of `if (i < arr1.length)`? This will always be true, since you're iterating through that array. Did you mean `arr2.length`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you don't need to make multiple passes. You can use a single map to get the value of the other array.

Also, you don't need to check that `i` is less than the length of the array, it is.

```js
var arr1 = [123, 234, 565];
var arr2 = [2, 5, 1];

result = arr1.map((x, i) => (x + '' + arr2[i]) / 100);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the numbers with a `.` instead of a space, then dividing by 10 instead of 100 and fixing the number to two decimal places:

```js
var arr1 = [123, 234, 565];
var arr2 = [2, 5, 1];

var arr = arr1.map(function(num, i) {
    if(i < arr1.length)
        return num + "." + arr2[i];

    return num;
});

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (parseFloat(arr[i])/10).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(arr);
```